# How to apply simple formatting to text in TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my application I need to view chat with smiles and simple formatting (bold, italic, underline and links) by parsing BB codes in message text. I am using the LongListSelector and TextBlock for chat viewing. On Android I make formatting with HTML tags like a `<img>`, `<a>`, `<b>`, `<i>` and `<u>`. But TextBlock doesn't support HTML. How to make formatting and smiles on Windows Phone 8?

Comment: [RichTextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227565) should provide what you're looking for when you mix in some [InlineUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlineuicontainer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This works for Windows Phone Silverlight 7.5/8/8.1, but not for WinRT style WP8.1 apps.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana" Foreground="White">
  <Run Text="Bold " FontWeight="Bold"/>
  <Run Text="Italic " FontStyle="Italic"/>
  <Run Text="Underline " TextDecorations="Underline"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Displaying image and hyperlink is more complex. You can't (to my knowledge) insert image or use events inside `TextBlock`. Most likely you need to make separate `TextBlock` for links which uses `Tap`event to launch navigation.